# CSRF Failed 403 when authenticated to admin, but same works fine when not authenticated

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, filter, django-queryset

Another newbie type of an issue, I guess.

AngularJS using PATCH method raises:

```
"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
```

Cookies:

```
Cookie:arp_scroll_position=0; sessionid=ix36xi2u9bijih2x1npswjlranfm7wjy; csrftoken=w54t2iWlU6oYBoYpeoZtkeWHluAgFmZOIbNeVsfo9pGgCD8OnPzoCdxJNmbfl2aM
```

But only when I'm authenticated in another tab into Admin panel.
Same request works fine if I'm not logged in.

```
Cookie:arp_scroll_position=0; csrftoken=w54t2iWlU6oYBoYpeoZtkeWHluAgFmZOIbNeVsfo9pGgCD8OnPzoCdxJNmbfl2aM
```

This is very simple JSON push:

```
.factory('MyName', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/resource/:pk/', {'pk': '@pk'}, {
      'update': {
        method: 'PATCH' // this method issues a PUT request
      },
    });
});
```

With JSON content such as `{"pk":3,"gt":"angularjs-auth"}`

At the same time, another "html" with separate AngularJS app defined works fine for both situations when authenticated and when not authenticated, but this time I'm using dropzone which probably does workaround the problem transparently for me.

```
.factory('UploadFile', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/files/:pk', {'pk': '@pk'}, {
        'save': {
            method: 'POST',
              transformRequest: transformImageRequest,
            headers: {'Content-Type':undefined}
        },
    });
});
```

Not Authenticade POST (not PATCH, but probably this doesn't make a difference):

```
Cookie:arp_scroll_position=0; csrftoken=w54t2iWlU6oYBoYpeoZtkeWHluAgFmZOIbNeVsfo9pGgCD8OnPzoCdxJNmbfl2aM
```

What I'm seeing here is that content is multipart/form-data which itself includes also CSRF (is this the trick fixing the issue?)

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryXUBwTTaSIiKwTvyx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"
```

And authenticated:

```
Cookie:sessionid=kaw00iaxwpq3puxcc94dy9v8yxf7rfyh; csrftoken=49KSaqsZykxuYRvJsEhpKlCyqP1ZnVQAubO4bPKs0u2qEcm0hpVvutMoIdUW9gV6; arp_scroll_position=0


------WebKitFormBoundaryelub0ZsHFENNbUmp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"

dqeieK1GdnYD9QTVRbt4ibQ6q0u8o8mkDsiuf9j9FxtzPbKcGW7a2j0WIon5atrQ
```

Looking for help and suggestions what to change as I'm certainly missing some tiny part to get it fixed.

{% csrf_token %} is part of html and tried to include it in  section  too.

At the same time, Postman works fine using "No auth" and "Basic Auth". Certainly it is not mirror situation as AngularJS PATCH, but it seems like I'm doing some silly mistake as only my AngularJS PATCH doesn't work.

**EDIT 1**

Following default elements, including authentication are part of settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Are you using Django REST Framework? If yes, what authentication backends do you have configured?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Django REST Framework. MIDDLEWARE:    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', and INSTALLED_APPS:     'django.contrib.auth', I've tried also with below, but didn't really solve the issue:
# Test for CSRF issue when AUthenticated
DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES = [
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
],

DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES = [
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks GwynBleidD for help and hints provided.
Dunno how it works, that I can be pulling my hair for hours trying to fix issue and once question posted/asked I'm finding solution.

In this case, all what I needed to do is following in my AngularJS code:

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
}]);
```

This fixed issue completely and works perfectly fine.

@GwynBleidD, I'd be glad to hear which authentication methods are recommended.

Answer (score 0):

With requests to Django REST Framework views, you don't usually need CSRF token...

Unless you're authenticated using session/cookie based authentication (doesn't matter if it's in admin or not).

You can get around it in two ways other than sending `multipart/form-data` with your CSRF token.

First way is to use [`X-CSRFToken` header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax) to pass your token in request (your JS logic must set that header when making requests)

Second way is to use another authentication method. It can be used together with cookie/session based one if it's higher on [list of authentication backends](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme) in your settings file. REST Framework will pick first one from the list that is valid and discard others, so session/cookie based one won't get a chance to enable CSRF verification.